# NSDate of yesterday

Tags: swift, nsdate

How do I create an `NSDate` object with a custom date other than the current date? For example I would like to create a var of yesterday or of 2 days ago.

Answer (score 74):

You should use [`NSCalendar`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/index.html) for calculating dates. For example, in Swift 3 the date two days before today is:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let twoDaysAgo = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -2, to: Date())
```

Or in Swift  2:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let twoDaysAgo = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: -2, toDate: NSDate(), options: [])
```

Or to get the first of the month, you can get the day, month and year from the current date, adjust the day to the first of the month, and then create a new date object. In Swift 3:

```
var components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: Date())
components.day = 1
let firstOfMonth = calendar.date(from: components)]
```

Or in Swift 2:

```
let components = calendar.components([.Year, .Month, .Day], fromDate: NSDate())
components.day = 1
let firstOfMonth = calendar.dateFromComponents(components)
```

There are lots of useful functions in the `NSCalendar`/`Calendar` class, so you should investigate that further. See the [NSCalendar class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/index.html) for more information.

But I would advise against doing any manual adjustments of date objects by adjusting it by some time interval that is a multiple of the seconds per day (e.g. 24*60*60). That technique works fine if you're just adding some time interval, but for date calculations, you really want to use calendar object, to avoid problems stemming from daylight savings and the like.

Comment: DayCalendarUnit is Deprecated in OS X v10.10.

Comment: you should change it to .CalendarUnitDay

Comment: let twoDaysAgo = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitDay, value: -2, toDate: NSDate(), options: nil)

Comment: Can't do nil apparently for options, not anymore at least, swift 2.1.

Comment: @NathanMcKaskle - Correct, in Swift 2 and latest API, it's `[]` now. And it's just `.Day`, too. Updated answer accordingly.

Comment: let twoDaysAgo = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: -2, toDate: NSDate(), options: []) it is not worked in ios 7

Comment: @kalpesh - Correct, `dateByAddingUnit` was introduced in iOS 8. To support iOS 7 you have to use the more cumbersome `dateByAddingComponents`. For example, `let components = NSDateComponents(); components.day = -2; let twoDaysAgo = calendar.dateByAddingComponents(components, toDate: NSDate(), options: [])`.

Comment: Swift 3.0 would be: `let twoDaysAgo = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -2, to: NSDate() as Date)!`

Comment: @Patrick - Or just `calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -2, to: Date())`.

Answer (score 31):

This is a solution for **Swift 5.1 - XCode 11**

```
let yesterday = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: Date())
```

Accordingly two days ago:

```
let twoDaysAgo = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -2, to: Date())
```

Comment: please replace `NSCalendar` with `Calendar`

Answer (score 2):

Code for Swift 2.0

```
static func yesterDay() -> NSDate {

    let today: NSDate = NSDate()

    let daysToAdd:Int = -1

    // Set up date components
    let dateComponents: NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()
    dateComponents.day = daysToAdd

    // Create a calendar
    let gregorianCalendar: NSCalendar = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
    let yesterDayDate: NSDate = gregorianCalendar.dateByAddingComponents(dateComponents, toDate: today, options:NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))!

    return yesterDayDate
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Rob's answer works great. If you are heavily using that kind of calculations you can even encapsulate that logic and make your own custom extensions and wrappers.

That said i will suggest to take a look too at this fantastic library called [SwiftDate](https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate). Even if you aren't using it, the README worth reading.
It introduces the definition or `Region` that can be super useful for some scenarios and some handy initializers.

Some cool stuffs and samples:

- Math operation with dates: `(1.years - 2.hours + 16.minutes).fromNow()`
- Composing time components: `let dateInUTC = (2015.years | 12.months | 25.days | 20.hours | 10.minutes).inUTCRegion`
- Classy: `let date = 5.days.fromNow`, `let date = 4.hours.ago`
- With Regions: `let date = (6.hours + 2.minutes).fromNow(region: inRome)`
- And a lot more ...

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
let twoDaysAgo = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: -2*24*60*60)
```

Comment: Fair enough, especially for intervals more complex than days.

Comment: This solution doesn't take DST into account.

Comment: @Andriy, true, as @Rob pointed out in a comment since deleted. Still, it depends on what you need the `NSDate` for. Sometimes something simple like the above will do, and sometimes the `NSCalendar` based solution is not quite right either: "Two days ago" may or may not mean "the exact same clock time on the day before yesterday".

Answer (score -4):

Please try below code. I think it's simple.

```
let today = NSDate()
let tomorrow = today.dateByAddingTimeInterval(24 * 60 * 60)
let yesterday = today.dateByAddingTimeInterval(-24 * 60 * 60)
```

Cheers!!!