# How do you get last weeks date in swift in YYYY-MM-DD format?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

How can I display date of one week ago in the format of YYYY-MM-DD like this one "2015-02-18" in Swift

Comment: Im not sure why my question is getting voted down. Did I do something wrong in my question?

Comment: You mean your question. That's because you did not post any code showing what you tried and what's not working.

Comment: oh okay, thanks! I knew NSDate gave the current date but I didnt know adding a date unit would give me a past date. So I guess Ill just post code thats obviously wrong next time?

Comment: Look at `NSCalendar`, specifically look on SO for similar questions regarding `NSCalendar`.  There're undoubtedly numerous examples here, or even google for it.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use Calendar's `date(byAdding component:)`  to calculate today minus a week and then you can format your date as desired using DateFormatter:

```
let lastWeekDate = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601).date(byAdding: .weekOfYear, value: -1, to: Date())!
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.calendar = .init(identifier: .iso8601)
dateFormatter.locale = .init(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let lastWeekDateString = dateFormatter.string(from: lastWeekDate)
```

Comment: I meant to comment and vote yours up. You submitted first with a working solution. I didn't want to rob you of points.

Comment: With Swift 2 you should now use ".WeekOfYear"

Comment: @leo Dabus will appreciate if you answer my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45238994/get-previous-current-and-next-weeks-excluding-saturday-and-sunday

Answer (score 5):

To get the date in a specific format you can use the `NSDateFormatter`:

```
var todaysDate:NSDate = NSDate()
var dateFormatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
var todayString:String = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(todaysDate)
```

`NSDate()` returns the current date

[For calculating date you should use calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26942123/nsdate-of-yesterday)

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let weekAgoDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnitdateByAddingUnit(.WeekOfYearCalendarUnit, value: -1, toDate: NSDate(), options: nil)!
var dateFormatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
var aWeekAgoString:String = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(weekAgoDate)
```

Comment: Note that to get the interval use: `var interval: NSTimeInterval = -60 * 60 * 24 * 7; var aWeekAgoToday = NSDate(timeInterval: interval, sinceDate: todaysDate)`

Comment: If you want more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26942123/nsdate-of-yesterday

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3:

```
        let lastWeekDate = NSCalendar.current.date(byAdding: .weekOfYear, value: -1, to: NSDate() as Date)
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        var aWeekBefore:String = dateFormatter.string(from: lastWeekDate!)
```

Answer (score 1):

Would extending NSDate be a bad idea?

```
import UIKit

extension NSDate {

    func previousWeek() -> NSDate {
        return dateByAddingTimeInterval(-7*24*60*60)
    }

    func asString(format:String) -> String {
        var dateFormatter : NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
        return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(self)
    }
}

NSDate().previousWeek().asString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Comment: The extension is ok but the way you implement it is not. first you don't need a function because there is no parameters, try creating a read-only computed property. You should also use the dateByAddingUnit instead of adding time interval.